# PHP Rearrange Array By Key

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array...

```
Array (
    ["advertisers"] => Array (
        ...,
        ...,
        ...
    ),
    ["general"] => Array (
        ...,
        ...,
        ...
    ),
    ["publishers"] => Array (
        ...,
        ...,
        ...
    )
)
```

I would like to rearrange the array so that `"advertisers"` comes first but `"publishers"` comes second and `"general"` is last.

Comment: Then what do you want to arrange by, if not alphabetically?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/ksort and http://php.net/uksort

Comment: @KevinL I have updated my question, this is more to do with my actual project

Comment: Sorry because I don't know how to do it, but, you can make a new array and asign your values. `$newarray = array($array['advertirsrers'], $array['publishers'], $array['general']);` and done. Just a way. :P

Comment: @Zerquix18 thank you, that's what I'm going with

Comment: Where is this array coming from? do you want the keys to be in alphabetical order and just place 'general' in the last place? or do you want it always in an order you specify?

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
<?
$fruits = Array( 
    "apples" => Array (
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
    ),
    "oranges" => Array (
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
    ),
    "bananas" => Array (
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
    )
);
ksort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
apples = Array 
bananas = Array  
oranges = Array
```

Comment: OP didn't say they wanted it alphabetically, they wanted A, P, then G.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ksort. It sorts the array in alphabetic order by the array keys. Something like this

```
<?php
 $arr = array('general'=>array(1,2,3), 'advertisers'=>array(7,8,9), 'publishers'=>array(11,12,13));
 ksort($arr);
 print '<pre>';
 print_r($arr);
 print '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
[advertisers] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 9
    )

[general] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
    )

[publishers] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11
        [1] => 12
        [2] => 13
    )

 )
```

Comment: OP didn't say they wanted it alphabetically, they wanted A, P, then G.